# two children problem given the father's probability to have a son or a girl

Tags: probability

**The problem:**

A couple has two children. We know that at least one of these is a boy. What is the probability that both children are boys given the following fact: $10$% of men can only produce sons, $10$% of men can only produce daughters, and $80$% are equally to produce either gender.

**My answer:**

The probability that both children are boys given at least $1$ is a boy and the above fact is $1/3$ (no difference from the answer to the classic problem, where the father's probability to have son or daughter is not taken into consideration).
My reason is that since we know at least $1$ child is a boy, we only consider the case where the father can have a son (which is $50$% of the time). Also, in the classic problem, it is (implicitly) only consider the case where the father can have a son. So there's no difference between the two problems. As a result, the probability is still $1/3$

My question is that is my reason/assumption correct? If not please show me the math behind it. Also, if the percentage of the father's probability to have a son or a daughter changes, will the answer be different? For example, $5$% of men can only produce son, $15$% can only produce daughters, and $80$% of men are equally likely to produce either gender.

Comment: To precisely specify the question, it might help to be more explicit about exactly what the random experiment is that you have in mind.  (Are you assuming that the couple is a male and a female, and that the male is selected at random from the population you describe?  And, by the event "at least one of these is a boy", do you mean to condition on that event?)

Comment: This problem is the classic conditional probability "Two children problem" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boy_or_Girl_paradox) with a twist. The twist is that given the same information -- two children, at least 1 child is a boy, what is the probability that both children are boys if we also know another fact -- 10% of men can only produce sons, 10% of men can only produce daughters, and 80% of men are equally likely to produce either gender

Comment: Right, and as your link says _"Gardner initially gave the answer... 1/3... but later acknowledged that the ... question was ambiguous.[3] Its answer could be 1/2, depending on how you found out that one child was a boy. The ambiguity, depending on the exact wording and possible assumptions, was confirmed by Bar-Hillel and Falk,[4] and Nickerson.[5]"._  Doesn't your question have the same ambiguity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't really follow the logic in the original post, but it isn't correct. The answer is $\frac3 7$.

Think of all the possible cases of father and children:

- boys only: boy boy
- girls only: girl girl
- both: boy boy
- both: girl girl
- both: boy girl
- both: girl boy

The top two possibilities each happen 10% of the time, while the others share the other 80%, so 20% each.

In total, 70% of the time there is at least one boy, and 30% of the time there are two. The result follows from a simple division.

Comment: In the original post, I was (wrongly) assume that both cases -- the classic "two children problem" without the father's probability to have boy or girl and the problem with the new twist -- have the same sample space. Is there a better approach to this problem than naively state out all the possible cases?

Answer (score 0):

Let $A,B,C$ stand for the events that the father can respectively: sire only boys, sire either without bias, and sire only girls. Let $X$ be the count of boys in the two child family.   The definition for conditional probability says:
$$\mathsf P(X=2\mid X>0)=\dfrac{\mathsf P(X=2\mid A)\mathsf P(A)+\mathsf P(X=2\mid B)\mathsf P(B)+0}{\mathsf P(X>0\mid A)\mathsf P(A)+\mathsf P(X>0\mid B)\mathsf P(B)+0}$$

Then apply the fact that $X$ will be binomial distributed conditioned on those events.

So then, $\mathsf P(X=2\mid A)=1$, and $\mathsf P(X=x\mid B)=\tfrac 14\binom 2x $ , for any $x\in\{0,1,2\}$

Comment: The final terms in the numerator and denominator are $0$ because $\mathsf P(X>0\mid C)=0$ , obviously.